# How to exclude a folder by name recursively when making a tar archive?

Tags: backup, tar, gzip

I know it is possible to exclude a particular folder by a command like this:

```
tar --exclude='/srv/www/project/node_modules' -zcvf /backup/project.tgz .
```

My question how to exclude any folder named `node_modules` anywhere within the entire `/srv/www` directory, to exclude it and exclude all folders under it?

Comment: If what you mean is you want to exclude all directories that start with `node_modules` in their names like `node_modules123` and `node_modules_new` etc. then append a `*` to the excluded directory name and use the command like so `tar -zcvf /backup/project.tar.gz --exclude "/srv/www/project/node_modules*" /srv/www/` and please [edit] your question and make it clear. Thank you

Comment: @Raffa, I have just re-edited my question and made it clearer.

Comment: This isn't an answer but an FYI.  When using the `--exclude` option, the syntax of the filename must match the path being tared.  In your example, the **exclude** option should be `--exclude=./srv/www/project/node_modules` in order for the match to occur and the directory to be excluded

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To exclude the directory named `node_modules` wherever it is located under `/srv/www/` even if there are multiple copies of it under different sub-directories, just do not specify a path in the `--exclude` part and use it like this:

```
tar -zcvf /backup/project.tar.gz --exclude "node_modules" /srv/www/
```

This will exclude all directories and files named exactly `node_modules` and all sub-directories and files under them anywhere in `/srv/www/`.

Comment: When using `zip`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410521/how-to-zip-a-lot-of-folders-but-exclude-any-subfolder-recursively-called-node#comment2530636_1410530