# How to ZIP a lot of folders but exclude any subfolder (recursively) called "node_modules"

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zip

I have a lot of directories in the initial folder and I want to zip everything , but exclude
all the `node_modules` folder of each directory , I tried this:

```
zip -r all_repos.zip . -x '*node_modules*'
```

But it doesn't exclude all sub-folders.

Any idea how to do it recursively ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` looks at files, so to make it include directories you need to add `/\*` or `'/*'` according to these instructions about 'include' in `man zip'

> ```
>           Examples are for Unix unless otherwise specified.]  So to include dir,
>           a directory directly  under  the current directory, use
>
>                  zip -r foo . -i dir/\*
>
>           or
>
>                  zip -r foo . -i "dir/*"
> ```

So let us assume it works to 'exclude' too, and try with

```
zip -r all_repos.zip . -x '*node_modules*/*'
```

Comment: Thanks! `zip -r ~/code_with_node_modules_excluded.zip ~/code/ -x '*node_modules*/*' -x '*vendor*/*' -x '*.cache*/*' -x '*.next*/*' -x '*target*/*'` was very helpful for me. 32G down to just 1.1G! (according to `cd ~/code/ && du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 10` and `du --max-depth=0 -h ~/code`)